# Keep getting " argument of type 'NoneType' " error in Python

Tags: python

I'm messing around with Google Speech Recognition in Python. The idea is that it will listen to what I say, and then give me back a response/action based on that. Here is the code:

```
import time
from gtts import gTTS
import os
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyaudio

r = sr.Recognizer()

def speak(audioString):
    print(audioString)
    tts = gTTS(text=audioString, lang='en')
    #tts.save("audio.mp3")
    #os.system("audio.mp3")

# obtain audio from the microphone
def recordAudio():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Listening")
    audio = r.listen(source)


# recognize speech using Google Speech Recognition
try:
    # using the default API key
    # to use another API key, use `r.recognize_google(audio, key="GOOGLE_SPEECH_RECOGNITION_API_KEY")`
    data = r.recognize_google(audio)

except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))

def assistant(data):
    if "how are you" in data:
        print("I am fine")

    if "what time is it" in data:
        print(ctime())   

    if "where is" in data:
        data = data.split(" ")
        location = data[2]
        speak("Hold on, I will show you where " + location + " is.")
        os.system("chromium-browser https://www.google.nl/maps/place/" + location + "/&amp;")

# initialization
time.sleep(3)
print("Hi, what can I do for you?")
print(data)
while 1:
    data = recordAudio()
    print(data)
    assistant(data)
```

Now, the error:

```
Listening
Hi, what can I do for you?
how are you
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/speechrecogtest.py", line 54, in <module>
    assistant(data)
  File "C:/Python34/speechrecogtest.py", line 35, in assistant
    if "how are you" in data:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

It's hearing what I'm saying, I have it printing that out. When I say "How are you" it should print out "I am fine" but is not...

I don't understand how this is a NoneType error. I have a feeling that it is not reading the data string in the arguments in the "def assistant(data):" area, because I've got a function messed up somewhere... This is definitely something stupidly obvious. What is wrong with those functions?

**EDIT:**

If I do something like:

```
print("Hi, what can I do for you?")
while 1:`
    data = recordAudio()
    if "how are you" in data:
        print("I am fine")
```

That works beautifully!
The problem is mainly that I am trying to call the `assistant(data)` function, so that it will say what I want it to say based on pre-defined responses.

I keep getting errors when I try to pass it to the `assistant(data)` function. That's really what I need help with, it looks like. I keep getting all sorts of errors when I try to get it to print from there

Comment: fix your indentation as `with sr.Microphone() as source:` is not part of the method declared above it right now.

Comment: also, what do you think `data = recordAudio()` does, given that `recordAudio` does not return anything?

Comment: Apparently `sr.Recognizer()` can return `None`. I guess if the sound isn't recognized?

Comment: Try `if data: assistant(data)`

Comment: I added an edit to clarify a bit :)